# How to find the compound of poisson and normal distribution?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

how to find the compound distribution, if the rate of poisson distribution is normally distributed with mean and variance ?
I know I have to find the integral of:

$$ \frac {1} {\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi} x!} \int_0^\infty \lambda^x e^{-{\lambda}} e^{- \frac{(\lambda - \mu)^{2}}{2 \sigma^2}} d \lambda $$

As you can see, the rate of possion distrbution $ \lambda $ is normally distributed with $ \mu$ and $\sigma$

As far as I know, you can do it easier with gamma-poisson distribution. Can anyone point me to the right integration technique ? I need the exact closed form solution of this compound distribution.

Comment: i doubt that there is a closed form solution. Maybe in the case of $\mu=0$ but the general case looks kopeless for me

Comment: i think the special case above can be written down in terms of Kummer's hypergeometric function. Would you consider this as a closed form solution?